# Parse/Facebook Javascript login issue with ios Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

Following the instructions here to create a Fb loginf ro my site using the Parse/JavaScript SDK https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#users-facebook-users

The following code section opens a pop up window, which causes means that the login does not work for Chrome ios [Facebook OAuth "Unsupported" in Chrome on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843116/facebook-oauth-unsupported-in-chrome-on-ios/28890740#28890740)

I cannot find a solution that works for Parse/Facebook (Only for Facebook).Chrome ios locks the pop up, so I need a different approach.

Is there a workaround for Chrome ios, can I avoid the pop up?

```
Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn(null, {
  success: function(user) {
    if (!user.existed()) {
      alert("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
    } else {
      alert("User logged in through Facebook!");
    }
  },
  error: function(user, error) {
    alert("User cancelled the Facebook login or did not fully authorize.");
  }
});
```

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @adamdport nope never, not using js anyway. Let me know if you crack it!