# Facebook “Unsupported” in Chrome on iOS in iframe

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, iframe

There is a question [Facebook OAuth "Unsupported" in Chrome on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843116/facebook-oauth-unsupported-in-chrome-on-ios/) where there are fixes with manually redirecting to login screen and back to the original url.

But, I have situation when login button is in the iframe within popup on some page. This popup could be displayed on multiple sites.

Redirect_uri should be the page of facebook application, in this example iframe inside popup. I need it to be redirecting on the original page.

Any ideas?

**Update**:
Even with Manual login flow, it doesn't work. It's not redirecting me anywhere after login. Just same facebook window with message "Please close this tab to proceed".

Comment: Store the “original” page URL into your session, and then redirect back there after the login flow comes back to your app URL …? (Or try to pass it as a GET parameter in the redirect_uri to begin with, if you don’t want to rely on sessions.)

Comment: Thanks, good idea.
But there is a problem that original solution (I mean solution for facebook on chrome) doesn't work.
It's not redirecting to uri, that I mentioned. It's just showing message close this tab.